# write yaml file in jenkins with groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

What is the best way to write/modify a *.yaml file in Groovy?

I would like to modify the version maintained in a yaml file within my jenkins pipeline job. With `readYaml` I can get the content, but how can I write it back again?

One way that comes to my mind would be to do a `sed` on the file. But I think thats not very accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [groovy load YAML file modify and write it in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668930/groovy-load-yaml-file-modify-and-write-it-in-a-file)

Comment: IMHO it's not a duplicate since it's not the equivalent to the Jenkins plugin's readYaml method

Comment: the recent jenkins plugin named "Pipeline utility steps" contains both `readYaml` (which reads yaml file into an object), and `writeYaml`, which takes an object and writes it down as yaml file.

Answer (score 37):

The [*Pipeline Utility Steps*](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) plugin has the `readYaml` and `writeYaml` steps to interact with YAML files. `writeYaml` will not overwrite your file by default so you have to remove it first.

```
def filename = 'values.yaml'
def data = readYaml file: filename

// Change something in the file
data.image.tag = applicationVersion

sh "rm $filename"
writeYaml file: filename, data: data
```

Comment: Frankly this is the savior: sh "rm $filename"

Comment: This should be THE answer.

Comment: You should think about situation that the source file removed ('sh "rm $filename"') and the program forced stopped in this situation the data will lost. you never trust the RAM.
Think about writing to temp file before removing after that remove the origin and rename the destination

Comment: Setting the overwrite flag to true is a better solution

Answer (score 10):

You can use "**writeYaml**" with a flag "**overwrite**" set to **true**.
This will allow making updates to YAML file in place.
By default, it is set to false.

You can read more about that in [Pipeline Utility Steps Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writeyaml-write-a-yaml-from-an-object-or-objects)

Comment: Simply saying: `writeYaml file: filePath, data: fileData, overwrite: true`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to update a version in a yaml file, then you can just read the contents, do a String replace and write back to your file.

As an example, here's a unit test that demonstrates this:

Suppose `src/test/resources` contains a file `version.yaml` that looks like:

```
version: '0.0.1'

anotherProperty: 'value'
```

---

```
@Test
void replaceVersion() {
    File yaml = new File("src/test/resources/version.yaml")
    println yaml.text

    String newVersion = "2.0.0"
    yaml.text = yaml.text.replaceFirst(/version: '.*'/, "version: '${newVersion}'")
    println yaml.text
}
```

Comment: Not if you don't know or don't care what version of the string you are going to replace.