# How to update the content of an existing yaml file with Pipeline Utility Steps plugin

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

In my jenkins pipeline I am reading data stored in yaml file using [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readproperties-code-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) plugin

I can read data from file, now I want to update the value and write it back to the file, like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {

    stage('JOb B ....'){
        steps{
            script{
               def datas = readYaml file:"${WORKSPACE}/Version.yml"
               echo datas.MAJOR_VERSION //output is 111

               datas = ['MAJOR_VERSION': '222']
               writeYaml file:"${WORKSPACE}/Version.yml", data: datas
            }
        }//steps
    }//stage

}//stages

}//pipeline
```

But I am getting error - Version.yml already exist:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/t-cicd-swarm-example_hdxts-job-B/Version.yml already exist.
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.conf.WriteYamlStep$Execution.run(WriteYamlStep.java:175)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.conf.WriteYamlStep$Execution.run(WriteYamlStep.java:159)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems it can only write a new file and it cannot overwrite the existing file. How to update the content of an existing yaml file from my script shown above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140974/write-yaml-file-in-jenkins-with-groovy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write yaml file in jenkins with groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140974/write-yaml-file-in-jenkins-with-groovy)

Comment: A good answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140974/write-yaml-file-in-jenkins-with-groovy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to delete or rename the original file before you overwrite it because the writeYaml method doesn't have an overwrite flag.

```
sh '''
  if [ -e Version.yaml ]; then
    rm -f Version.yaml
  fi
'''
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the latest documentation. There is a parameter you can use to overwrite the content of designated file:

```
writeYaml: Write a yaml from an object.
...
overwrite (optional): Allow existing files to be overwritten. Defaults to false.
```

Please refer to: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writeyaml-write-a-yaml-from-an-object

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the plugin supports now the overwrite option.