# Jenkins writeYaml not replacing value in yaml file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-groovy

I have a yaml file with the following structure:

```
transfers:
- name: xyz
  cloud: aws
  subheading:
    impact: Low
    reason: ---

  artifacts:
  - name: name1
    type: type1
    source:
      hash: a1b2C3dd4    ---> VALUE TO OVERWRITE
```

I would like to overwrite the existing hash value with a value of the latest `GIT_COMMIT`.

I have tried the method from the following question: [write yaml file in jenkins with groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140974/write-yaml-file-in-jenkins-with-groovy). However, the value of `hash[0][0]` remains unchanged. This is the case even when I replace `env.GIT_COMMIT` with a test hash string "testHash123". I'm unsure why this is the case?

```
def filename = ('path/to/file.yaml')
def datas = readYaml file: filename
//change hash
datas.transfers['artifacts'].source.hash[0][0] = env.GIT_COMMIT
writeYaml file: filename, data: datas, overwrite: true
```

Comment: That gives a type error, because datas.transfers.artifacts.source.hash is of type arrayList and env.GIT_COMMIT is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
datas.transfers[0]['artifacts'][0]['source'].hash = env.GIT_COMMIT
```

The easiest way to figure this out is by printing, so you can understand the structure.

```
[transfers:[[name:xyz, cloud:aws, subheading:[impact:Low, reason:xxxx], artifacts:[[name:name1, type:type1, source:[hash:a1b2C3dd4]]]]]]
```

As you can see above the transfer is a sequence, so you need to extract the correct segment with an index.

Comment: That worked! I wonder why datas.transfers['artifacts'].source.hash[0][0] worked?